# How to calculate the center of mass for a cloud of 3D spheres?

Tags: 3d, spheres, centroid

Given the spheres in 3D space:  center(xi,yi,zi), radius and density and the info is stored in an array 
sphere_data[n][5]:

---

// Sphere_ID   x   y  z  radius   density

1   x1   y1  z1  rad1  density_1

2   x2   y2  z2  rad2  density_2

...

n   xn   yn  zn  radn  density_n

---

So how to calculate the center of mass for this cloud of 3D sphere?

Any tips or recommendation would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the center of the mass of the system is $(x,y,z)$, we then have
$$x = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i}$$
$$y = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i}$$
$$z = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac43\pi r_i^3\rho_i} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^3\rho_i}$$

Comment: Thanks user17762! Can you please give some literature on this equations? I want to see how it is derived

Comment: @KOF Center of mass coordinates is given by
$$\vec{x} = \dfrac{\sum_i m_i \vec{x}_i}{\sum_i m_i}$$
where $m_i$ and $\vec{x}_i$ denotes the mass and location of the $i^{th}$ object. [Look up here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)

Answer (score 1):

Static balance. Taking moment of combined cloud of spheres or cubes and from that of the effect gravity point.Compute $ m_i = \rho_i \ r_i^3, \;\  x_i^2 + y_i^2 +z_i^2= r_i^2, $

$$ \bar X = \dfrac{\Sigma\ x_i m_i}{\Sigma \ m_i} ;\ \bar  Y = \dfrac{\Sigma\ y_i m_i}{\Sigma \ m_i};\  \bar Z = \dfrac{\Sigma\ z_i m_i}{\Sigma \ m_i} ;\ $$